# Is there any API can transform any compatible web page into more readable textview in cocoa?

Tags: cocoa, web

As the title tells,is there any API has the similar function with instapaper text feature in cocoa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not really an API, but there is [open source javascript code](http://code.google.com/p/arc90labs-readability/) from readability that does more or less what you need. With some hacking you could get this to work for you I'm sure.

Comment: I am not sure how do i make the javascript code work with cocoa webview,how do i deal with the js and css file?I am not familiar with javascript and css..

Comment: It will be a good deal of work and I can only provide some hints as to what to do. Like: execute the JavaScript on your WebView to unleash the readability magic, and: access the DOM from Cocoa to get the text out of the WebView. Good luck!